# Application pools can not be started unless the Windows Process Activation Service(WAS) is running

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7

> Application pools can not be started unless the Windows Process
>   Activation Service(WAS)  is running.

This is issue is coming while starting application pool in IIS 7 (windows 7 professional operation system).

Please suggest how to run Windows Process Activation Service(WAS) in windows 7.

Comment: The text that you've quoted is part of an explanation of how the app pool process activation works - it doesn't explain what issue you're having.  Please provide more information.

Answer (score 4):

WAS is part of IIS. When you install IIS, WAS is installed.

In Vista / 2008, it was installed explicitly as a feature dependency.

In Windows 7 (I assume) and R2 (I know), it's silently installed because (insert non-obvious reason here).

You can explicitly install it as well, but if IIS is installed, it should be there.

So the question becomes: *Did someone disable WAS because they thought it was related to Windows Activation?*

If so, **slap them**, and get them to re-enable it.

Comment: Some more clarity here, full service name: Windows Process Activation Service. Another note, in my case, W3SVC or World Wide Web Publishing Service needs to be checked/started

Comment: It needs the Windows-Features  .NET Framework 3.5 Feature "Non-HTTP Activation" and 
.NET Framework 4.7 Feature "Named Pipe Activation/TCP Activation". If those are installed, it works. If those are missing, you get this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Someone may have made changes to %windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config resulting in an invalid config file.

Adding preloadEnabled="true" to some of the application pool `<application>` tags broke it for us and we had to remove those attributes to be able to start the WAS service and then the application pools.